# Jquery trouble with select options on html()

Tags: jquery, html

When i call the  on click with html() didn't work the options on

JS:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.pls', function() {
        $(".pls").html('<select id="plselect"><option value="list1">list1</option><option value="list2">list2</option</select><br>');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pls">pls</div>
```

^This Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/B5xqp/1/

Comment: It works on jsfiddle...

Comment: did you add the script in your page head

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the added **`select`** is within the class **`.pls`**, the **`click`** event is causing the trouble.

So do like this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.pls', function() {
        $(".pls").html('<select id="plselect"><option value="list1">list1</option><option value="list2">list2</option</select><br>');
    $(document.body).off('click');  
});
```

Once the **`select`** is added to the class, remove the **`click`** event using [**`.off()`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) event handler attachment.

### [JSFiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/B5xqp/13/)

**Updates:**  Based on your comments it seems you don't want to remove the event handler.  So if I understood correctly you can try like this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.pls', function () {
    $(".pls").after('<select id="plselect"><option value="list1">list1</option><option value="list2">list2</option</select><br>');
});
```

### [JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/B5xqp/14/)

Comment: @Brad Thank you, glad to hear from you :)

Comment: yes this works if disable the click event, but i need it on, i have like ~20divs clickables

Comment: @Rz-- I understood, try like this http://jsfiddle.net/QCtvU/1/ Once select is added remove the `pls` class